# RAC database fails to start

Tags: oracle-12c, rac

I encountered the below errors when i am trying to start the RAC DB/instances.

The Cluster/CRS is up but could not bring up the RAC DB instances.

***Environment:   2 Node RAC (12cr2) on Linux 7.3***

[grid@Server-666 ~]$ /oragrid/app/grid_home/bin/srvctl start database -db rac

PRCR-1079 : Failed to start resource ora.rac.db

CRS-5017: The resource action "ora.rac.db start" encountered the following error:

ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/ora00/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/dbs/initrac2.ora'

. For details refer to "(:CLSN00107:)" in "/oragrid/app/grid_base/diag/crs/server-777/crs/trace/crsd_oraagent_oracle.trc".

CRS-2674: Start of 'ora.rac.db' on 'server-777' failed

CRS-5017: The resource action "ora.rac.db start" encountered the following error:

ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/ora00/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/dbs/initrac1.ora'

. For details refer to "(:CLSN00107:)" in "/oragrid/app/grid_base/diag/crs/server-666/crs/trace/crsd_oraagent_oracle.trc".

CRS-2674: Start of 'ora.rac.db' on 'server-666' failed

CRS-2632: There are no more servers to try to place resource 'ora.rac.db' on that would satisfy its placement policy

## ================================================================================

**Attempt to startup RAC  DB instance 1 (rac1) fails ... even if i point it to the default parameter file stored in ASM**

1)

SQL> startup

ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/ora00/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/dbs/initrac1.ora'

2)

echo "SPFILE='+DATA/RAC/PARAMETERFILE/spfile.272.1014397511'" >

SQL> startup

ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

ORA-01565: error in identifying file '+DATA/RAC/PARAMETERFILE/spfile.272.1014397511'

ORA-17503: ksfdopn:10 Failed to open file +DATA/RAC/PARAMETERFILE/spfile.272.1014397511

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

SQL>

## ================================================================================

[grid@SERVER-666 ~]$ srvctl config database -d rac

Database unique name: RAC

Database name: RAC

Oracle home: /ora00/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1

Oracle user: oracle

Spfile: +DATA/RAC/PARAMETERFILE/spfile.272.1014397511

Password file: +DATA/RAC/PASSWORD/pwdrac.256.1014397199

Domain:  xxxx.xxxx.com

Start options: open

Stop options: immediate

Database role: PRIMARY

Management policy: AUTOMATIC

Server pools:

Disk Groups: DATA,UNDO_DISK,LOB_DISK

Mount point paths:

Services: aptra

Type: RAC

Start concurrency:

Stop concurrency:

OSDBA group: dba

OSOPER group: oper

Database instances: RAC1,RAC2

Configured nodes: server-666,server-777

CSS critical: no

CPU count: 0

Memory target: 0

Maximum memory: 0

Default network number for database services:

Database is administrator managed

## ================================================================================

**===> Attempt to start RAC service fail.**

[grid@server-666 ~]$ srvctl start service -d rac -s aptra

PRCD-1133 : failed to start services aptra for database rac

PRCR-1095 : Failed to start resources using filter ((NAME == ora.rac.aptra.svc) AND (TYPE == ora.service.type))

CRS-5017: The resource action "ora.rac.db start" encountered the following error:

ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/ora00/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/dbs/initrac2.ora'

. For details refer to "(:CLSN00107:)" in "/oragrid/app/grid_base/diag/crs/server-777/crs/trace/crsd_oraagent_oracle.trc".

CRS-2674: Start of 'ora.rac.db' on 'server-777' failed

CRS-5017: The resource action "ora.rac.db start" encountered the following error:

ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

ORA-01565: error in identifying file '+DATA/rac/PARAMETERFILE/spfile.272.1014397511'

ORA-17503: ksfdopn:10 Failed to open file +DATA/rac/PARAMETERFILE/spfile.272.1014397511

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

. For details refer to "(:CLSN00107:)" in "/oragrid/app/grid_base/diag/crs/server-666/crs/trace/crsd_oraagent_oracle.trc".

CRS-2674: Start of 'ora.rac.db' on 'server-666' failed

CRS-2632: There are no more servers to try to place resource 'ora.rac.aptra.svc' on that would satisfy its placement policy

## ================================================================================

**===> Crs and ASM are up,**

[grid@SERVER-666 ~]$ crsctl check cluster

CRS-4537: Cluster Ready Services is online

CRS-4529: Cluster Synchronization Services is online

CRS-4533: Event Manager is online

[grid@SERVER-666 ~]$ crsctl check cluster -all

---

server-666:

CRS-4537: Cluster Ready Services is online

CRS-4529: Cluster Synchronization Services is online

CRS-4533: Event Manager is online

---

server-777:

CRS-4537: Cluster Ready Services is online

CRS-4529: Cluster Synchronization Services is online

CRS-4533: Event Manager is online

---

[grid@SERVER-666~]$ srvctl config scan

SCAN name: aptra-cluster-scan, Network: 1

Subnet IPv4: 192.168.119.0/255.255.255.0/ens224, static

Subnet IPv6:

SCAN 1 IPv4 VIP: 192.168.119.16

SCAN VIP is enabled.

SCAN VIP is individually enabled on nodes:

SCAN VIP is individually disabled on nodes:

SCAN 2 IPv4 VIP: 192.168.119.18

SCAN VIP is enabled.

SCAN VIP is individually enabled on nodes:

SCAN VIP is individually disabled on nodes:

SCAN 3 IPv4 VIP: 192.168.119.17

SCAN VIP is enabled.

SCAN VIP is individually enabled on nodes:

SCAN VIP is individually disabled on nodes:

**[root@SERVER-666 ~]# /oragrid/app/grid_home/bin/srvctl status asm**

ASM is running on SERVER-666,SERVER-777

Name           Target  State        Server                   State details

---

Local Resources

---

ora.ASMNET1LSNR_ASM.lsnr

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.CRS.dg

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.DATA.dg

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.LISTENER.lsnr

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.LOB_DISK.dg

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.MGMT.dg

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.REDO_A.dg

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.REDO_B.dg

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.UNDO_DISK.dg

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.chad

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.net1.network

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.ons

```
           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE

           ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

---

Cluster Resources

---

ora.LISTENER_SCAN1.lsnr

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE
```

ora.LISTENER_SCAN2.lsnr

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.LISTENER_SCAN3.lsnr

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.MGMTLSNR

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             169.254.240.140 10.1

                                                         0.1.3,STABLE
```

ora.asm

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             Started,STABLE

  2        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             Started,STABLE

  3        OFFLINE OFFLINE                               STABLE
```

ora.cvu

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.mgmtdb

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             Open,STABLE
```

ora.rac.aptra.svc

```
  1        ONLINE  OFFLINE                               STABLE

  2        OFFLINE OFFLINE                               STABLE
```

ora.rac.db

```
  1        ONLINE  OFFLINE                               STABLE

  2        ONLINE  OFFLINE                               STABLE
```

ora.qosmserver

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.scan1.vip

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE
```

ora.scan2.vip

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.scan3.vip

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

ora.SERVER-666.vip

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-666             STABLE
```

ora.SERVER-777.vip

```
  1        ONLINE  ONLINE       SERVER-777             STABLE
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, its due to file permission issue under $GRID_HOME

ls -l $GRID_HOME/bin/oracle

chmod 6751 $GRID_HOME/bin/oracle

Once permissions are fixed, try restarting db services.